# Laravel Production server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I’m getting an error when trying to put my laravel application on a production server. I have enabled mod_rewrite on my server and changed the permissions for app/storage

“Error in exception handler”

This is my .htaccess file

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /escrow/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

And this is my file for my virtual host:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride all
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your apache.conf. This is working in my apache.conf

```html
<Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Instead of the previous error, I get "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: hmm, its a strange.. have you restart your apache service ?